# Rails: Checking value selected in a drop-down and comparing to a value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I'm building a customer database for my father's landscaping company as a pet project. I've run into a roadblock with some code.

I've got three tables interacting with each other here: Clients, Invoices and Services (nested under Invoices). In the clients table, there are prices stored for each service performed (e.g., cut, bushes, mulch). If the client doesn't receive that service, the entry is null. I've stored the prices this way because each client is charged a different set amount for a service depending on the size of their property.

When adding a service to an invoice, I want to check the service selected in the drop-down against the price set in the client table, and give an error if its null (if the customer doesn't receive that service). For example, if `"Cut"` is selected, I'd like to compared that to (I think) `@invoice.client.cut`

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this. How would you have code like this run when the submit button is clicked?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Here's what the form looks like in its current state:

```
<%= form_for [@invoice, @service] do |f| %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:name, options_for_select([['Cut', 'Cut'], ["Mulch", "Mulch"],['Bushes', 'Bush'], ['Spring clean-up', 'Spring'], ['Fall clean-up', 'Fall'], ['Snow removal', 'Snow']])) %>
    </div>
  </div>    

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select(:category, options_for_select([["Maintenance", "Maintenance"], ["Seasonal", "Seasonal"]])) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>  
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Would `<% if @invoice.client.cut == "Cut" %>` work in this case? Need to end it with `<% end %>` but it works like any if/else conditional. Make sure not to put in the equal sign after the percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add at data-attribute somewhere in the view that lists the customer's current services, possible on the label for that dropdown. You can then use javascript to verify that the option selected is available to the user without making a call to the database.

```
<%= f.label :name, 'data-services' => @invoice.client.services %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the validity of the selected value when the user chooses it, don't even show the value in the dropdown. The user experience is different than you described, but not necessarily worse.

The architecture of querying the different kinds of services a client has should be improved by an extra model, but using the methods you already have:

```
<%= f.select(
  :name,
  options_for_select(
    [
      ['Cut', 'Cut'],
      ['Mulch', 'Mulch'],
      ['Bushes', 'Bush'],
      ['Spring clean-up', 'Spring'],
      ['Fall clean-up', 'Fall'],
      ['Snow removal', 'Snow']
    ].select do |a|
      @invoice.client.public_send(a.last.downcase)
    end
  )
) %>
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Much better than what I wanted to implement. I didn't know about public_send, that's super useful! Thank you!